# The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments specifically

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to use Expressions and Generics to create a set generic methods to help build dictionaries where the type of the key and value for the dictionary could be of any type.

So far I've got:

```
public class DictionaryServices<T>
{
    private readonly IGenericRepository<T> _repo;

    public DictionaryServices(IGenericRepository<T> repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public Dictionary<TKey, TValue> BuildDictionary<TObject, TKey, TValue>(Expression<Func<TObject, TKey>> keyExp, Expression<Func<TObject, TValue>> valueExp)
    {
        var allItems = _repo.GetAll();
        Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
        foreach (var item in allItems)
        {
            var keyMe = keyExp.Body as MemberExpression;

            dictionary.Add(GetValue(keyExp, item), GetValue(valueExp, item));
        }
        return dictionary;
    }

    private TType GetValue<TObject, TType>(Expression<Func<TObject, TType>> exp, TObject item)
    {
        var me = exp.Body as MemberExpression;
        var propInfo = me.Member as PropertyInfo;
        return (TType)propInfo.GetValue(item, null);
    }
}
```

When I compile I get the error "The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments specifically." for both usages of GetValue but I can't see why. If I remove the GetValue function and replicate what it is doing for both key and value in the foreach then it works fine. Does anyone have any ideas why I would be getting this error?

Comment: And what type `_repo.GetAll()` returns? It should return some list of `TObject` for this to compile, but it's not possible because `GetAll` is not generic call.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the post with the full class - now shows the definition of _repo

Comment: GetAll returns a list of T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `TObject` generic parameter in your `BuildDictionary` definition, because you already have `T` parameter on your *class* definition with the same meaning (that is - `T` is type of object in your repository). So change `BuildDictionary` like this:

```
public Dictionary<TKey, TValue> BuildDictionary<TKey, TValue>(
    Expression<Func<T, TKey>> keyExp, 
    Expression<Func<T, TValue>> valueExp)
```

You can also remove `TObject` from `GetValue`, though this is not required:

```
private TType GetValue<TType>(Expression<Func<T, TType>> exp, T item)
```

Your current approach does not work because you have two different generic type parameters with the same meaning: `T` on class level and `TObject` on method level. Your `_repo.GetAll()` returns list of `T`, but method works with objects of type `TObject` which might be different.